# Limited Multiselect in open file dialog?

Tags: vb.net

I want the user to have the option to select multiple files through openfiledialog which I have in my code, but then if the user selects a file from one folder he is then restricted to select another file only from this specific folder. What is the best way to approach to this problem?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openfiledialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    With openfiledialog1
        .Title = "Select your models"
        .Filter = "Solidworks Files|*.sldprt;"
        .Multiselect = True
    End With
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each mfile As String In openfiledialog1.FileNames
            
        '' Add all filenames in a txt file, in a column
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could roll your own form that allows the user to navigate folders and select files from multiple directories, adding all selections to another control as you go (maybe a ListBox?).

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you want the user to be able to open the dialogue once and select multiple files from different folders at the same time? This question has a comment and an answer that have interpreted it in two completely different ways and either could be valid based on the wording.

Comment: I want the user to be able to open files from multiple folders, but when he selects a file from one of the folders, he then can select another file only from that folder where he selected the first one. So, to try to make it more clear, because I'm saving the file names of the files that user has selected I wanted to prevent the user to go into one folder and choose one file and then go to another and select another one, within the same file dialog box. But as I tried to go into it more deeper it seems that by default the open file dialog doesn't allow multiselect from different folders

Comment: @Marc _"I wanted to prevent the user to go into one folder and choose one file and then go to another and select another one, within the same file dialog box. But as I tried to go into it more deeper it seems that by default the open file dialog doesn't allow multiselect from different folders"_ Re: So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, OpenFileDialog doesn't offer a way to prevent the user from navigating to another directory.

One approach would be to create a class-level variable that holds the value of the recently used directory path. Then, whenever a new file is selected, you check its directory path against the one previously stored. If it matches, continue. If not, break the operation and report to the user.

Here's a complete example:

```
Private openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
Private modelsDirectory As String = Nothing

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With openFileDialog1
        .Title = "Select your models"
        .Filter = "Solidworks Files|*.sldprt;"
        .Multiselect = True
        .FileName = Nothing
        ' Open the dialog and navigate to the previous direcoty by default.
        .InitialDirectory = modelsDirectory
    End With
    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub

    Dim dirPath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    If modelsDirectory IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
       Not dirPath.Equals(modelsDirectory, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Models must be selected from the following directory:" &
                        vbNewLine & modelsDirectory, "Restricted Directory")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Store the value of the current directory path.
    modelsDirectory = dirPath
    For Each filePath As String In openFileDialog1.FileNames
        ' TODO: use the selected files as you see fit.
    Next
End Sub
```

You might want to remove this restriction at some point (e.g., if you clear the list of selected files). You can achieve that by simply setting `modelsDirectory` to `Nothing`:

```
Private Sub ClearFilesList
    ' TODO: clear the files.

    modelsDirectory = Nothing
End Sub
```